# Is it possible to add Multiple jobs via JIL in Autosys by defining them in a single .jil file?

Tags: autosys

I have to move the jobs from one environment to another so, is it possible to bulk add the jobs via single .jil file/command

```
jil < alljobs.jil
```

Comment: It works! 
I was a bit hesitant to test it out on my own as its a live environment.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can jil multipel jobs at a time using Vi eiditor. i have jilled approx  150 jobs at a time

create a file using vi eiditor copy past the jobs in the file in vi editor and the save the file

then u can jil it using the below command

jil < filename.txt

u get the exit code accordingly

Regards
Som

Answer (score 0):

I've added upwards of 200-500 jobs within a single job before. It only becomes a pain when you start running into errors. Tracking them down and keeping things running smoothly can be a pain.

I prefer to keep my jil and jil changes as separate job streams and then place them under version control like git.

It makes tracking changes to production jobs over time a lot easier.